# Getting type of the caller of a property with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm writing a CSharpSyntaxRewriter and trying to get the type of a property node's owner. I cannot retrieve it correctly when there is class inheritance.

The sample code being parsed

```
class BaseClass
{
    public string MyProperty => "hello";
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    void MyMethod()
    {
        var withThis = this.MyProperty == "hello";
        var withoutThis = MyProperty == "hello";
    }
}
```

Code of the CSharpSyntaxRewriter

```
...
// this.MyProperty or object.MyProperty, used by first line of MyMethod
var memberAccess = node as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
if (memberAccess?.Name.Identifier.Text == "MyProperty")
{
    var type = SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(memberAccess.Expression).Type; // type is DerivedClass
...
...
// MyProperty (MyProperty access without this), used by second line of MyMethod
var identifier = node as IdentifierNameSyntax;
if (identifier?.Identifier.Text == "MyProperty")
{
    var type2 = SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(identifier).Type; // type is string
    var symbolInfo = SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(identifier);
    var type = symbolInfo.Symbol.ContainingType; // type is BaseClass
    var ds = SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(identifier); // null
    var pp = SemanticModel.GetPreprocessingSymbolInfo(identifier); // empty
...
```

How could I retrieve DerivedClass (instead of BaseClass) from the identifierNameSyntax (assuming its always a property)

I guess it is possible by getting it from ancestor nodes (from method or class declaration), but still wondering if is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think there is any better way.  Beware of nested classes and static imports.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
var containingClass = node;
while (!(containingClass is ClassDeclrationExpressionSyntax))
{
    containingClass = containingClass.Parent;
}
```

There can be some problems with Generics\Nested classes, but they are solvable.

Comment: Well, yeah I solved it that way. But I was expecting a solution without accessing the parent node or an extension/helper method from Roslyn source code.

Comment: There is a way, where you find all ClassDeclarationSyntaxes, define startLine \ endLine using Spans, than define a start line for your node - and use between. No access to parent node, but still problems with nested classes. If you need it - can find an example.